# Create codable struct with generic type

Tags: swift, codable

First of all, Sorry for unclear title of question

I'm making a codable struct which will be used as json message.

```
enum MessageType: String, Codable{
    case content
    case request
    case response
}

struct Message: Codable{
    var type: MessageType
    var content: /* NEED HELP HERE */
}

struct Content: Codable {...}
struct Request: Codable {...}
struct Response: Codable {...}
```

When declaring `Message`, if its `type` is `content`, its `content`'s type should be `Content`.

```
let message = Message(
    type: .content,
    content: Content( ... )
}
```

When `type` is `request`, its `content`'s type should be `Request`.

```
let message = Message(
    type: .request,
    content: Request( ... )
}
```

Then, How should I set `content` property's type?

I tried to make it as `String` like this way :

```
struct Message: Codable{
    var type: MessageType
    var content: String
}

struct Content: Codable{
    var jsonString: String{
        return String(data: try! JSONEncoder().encode(self), encoding: .utf8)
    }
}

let foo = Message(
    var type: .content,
    var content: Content ( ... ).jsonString
)
```

and I could use it, But I'm aware of using it in different platforms like Android, So I want to get more smart way to deal with this.

Comment: content and request are dictionary ?

Comment: No, `Content` and `Request` are codable struct, too.

Comment: by the way codable struct always dictionary

Comment: use it as dynamic try this [string: Any] , and then map your object

Comment: oops, I'll try it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use generic like below:

```
struct Message<T:Codable>: Codable{
    var type: MessageType
    var content: T
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't knew about generic!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in **Message** Struct

```
var content: [String: Any]
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but it gives me `Type 'Message' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'` error ;(

Comment: its because keys are not defined in Message struct