# Swift Codable with nested json as string

Tags: json, swift, swift4, codable

The services I use for backend calls returns all this json-structure:

```
{
    "status" : "OK",
    "payload" : **something**
}
```

Where **something** can be a simple string:

```
{
    "status" : "OK",
    "payload" : "nothing changed"
}
```

or a nested json (any json with any properties), for example:

```
{
    "status" : "OK",
    "payload" : {
                    "someInt" : 2,
                    "someString" : "hi",
                    ...
                }
}
```

This is my struct:

```
struct GenericResponseModel: Codable {

    let status:String?
    let payload:String?
}
```

**I want to decode "payload" always as a string**. So in the second case I want that the payload property of my "GenericResponseModel" contains the json string of that field, but If I try to decode that response I get the error:

```
Type 'String' mismatch: Expected to decode String but found a dictionary instead
```

Is possible to archive what I want?

Many thanks

Comment: Yes, this is possible by specifying how your `GenericResponseModel ` should decode itself. Check `init(from decoder: Decoder)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50674899/6630644

Comment: This service returns a JSON with a key that might have different types?

Comment: @JBL: yes, it can return different object types, based on the service endpoint

Comment: In that case it looks like you'll need to decode `payload` as a string first, and if it fails, as an arbitrary JSON, and [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44603248/1594913). Then serialize it (e.g. through JSONSerialization to Data to String with [`init?(data:encoding:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1418413-init) )

Comment: I'd suggest you speak to your backend team and suggest they improve their naming - e.g. `payload` when it's JSON, and `message` for a `String`. Or use the `someString` field in `Payload`, and make `someInt` optional

Comment: the fact that this has only gotten a few dozen upvotes and no reasonable answer in 1.5 years makes me wonder what is going on in the swift community :P

Answer (score 4):

How about this…

Declare a `PayloadType` protocol…

```
protocol PayloadType: Decodable { }
```

and make `String`, and `struct Payload` conform to it…

```
extension String: PayloadType { }

struct Payload: Decodable, PayloadType {
    let someInt: Int
    let someString: String
}
```

Then make `GenericResponseModel` generic…

```
struct GenericResponseModel<T: PayloadType>: Decodable {

    let status: String
    let payload: T

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case status, payload
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        status = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .status)            
        payload = try container.decode(T.self, forKey: .payload)
    }
}
```

Then you can decode as follows…

```
let data = """
{
"status" : "OK",
"payload" : "nothing changed"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

print(try JSONDecoder().decode(GenericResponseModel<String>.self, from: data))

// GenericResponseModel<String>(status: "OK", payload: "nothing changed")
```

and

```
let data2 = """
{
"status" : "OK",
"payload" : {
"someInt" : 2,
"someString" : "hi"
}
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

print(try JSONDecoder().decode(GenericResponseModel<Payload>.self, from: data2))

// GenericResponseModel<Payload>(status: "OK", payload: Payload(someInt: 2, someString: "hi"))
```

Of course, this relies on you knowing the `payload` type in advance. You could get around this by throwing a specific error if payload is the wrong type…

```
enum GenericResponseModelError: Error {
    case wrongPayloadType
}
```

and then…

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    status = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .status)

    do {
        payload = try container.decode(T.self, forKey: .payload)
    } catch {
        throw GenericResponseModelError.wrongPayloadType
    }
}
```

Then handle this error when you decode…

```
let data = """
{
"status" : "OK",
"payload" : {
"someInt" : 2,
"someString" : "hi"
}
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(GenericResponseModel<String>.self, from: data) // Throws
    print(response) 
} catch let error as GenericResponseModelError where error == .wrongPayloadType {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(GenericResponseModel<Payload>.self, from: data2) // Success!
    print(response)
}
```

Comment: Also in this case, It won't work on all kind of json-object contained in "payload" but only with the example I made. Payload can be every kind of object.

Comment: How can we be expected to answer the question when you don't give all the relevant information? Also, I don't believe _"Payload can be every kind of object."_ - if it can be literally _anything_, then `Codable` is the wrong solution. Use `JSONSerialization` and create a Dictionary from your JSON.  Do you actually mean _"The payload varies for each request"_?

Comment: In the question is written "any json with any properties", so all informations has been given. In fact, my question is how to treat the param as a string, regardless its real type, and I just asked if this goal could be reached.