# Swift Codable: generic solution for different server answers at same key

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have server with API responses that looks like:

```
{
  "result": true
}

{
  "result": {"aaa":"bbb"}
}

{
  "result":[{"aaa":"bbb"},{"aaa":"bbb"}]
}
```

Now I use JSONDecoder with structs like this:

```
struct MyObject: Codable {
    var aaa: String
}

struct ResultTrue: Codable {
    var result: Bool
}

struct ResultMyObjectDict: Codable {
    var result: MyObject
}

struct ResultMyObjectArray: Codable {
    var result: [MyObject]
}
```

But it looks overwhelmed - I use ResultTrue.self, ResultMyObjectDict.self, ResultMyObjectArray.self and always check .result...

Can I tell to JSON decoder, that my data is always located at key `result` and use something like simple Bool.self, MyObject.self, [MyObject].self with
    struct MyObject: Codable {
        var aaa: String
    }
?

Comment: You should use `enum`s here.

Comment: Also, using [this tool](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=swift) is quite handy, accepted answer in duplicate question was using it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54020428/6630644

Comment: @SPatel, exactly I needed and very beautiful solution, thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50674899/6630644