# (Swift) Parse JSON with JSONDecoder that has an object that changes structure depending on message

Tags: json, swift, decode

Problem basically comes down to this. My app is receiving messages in this JSON format:

```
{
    "action": "ready",
    "data": null
}
```

or

```
{
    "action": "error",
    "data": {
        "code": String,
        "exception": String,
        "status": Int
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "action": "messageRequest",
    "data": {
        "recipientUserId": String,
        "platform": String,
        "content": String
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "action": "tabsChange",
    "data": {
        "roomsTabs": [{
            "configuration": {
                "accessToken": STRING,
                "url": STRING,
                "userId": STRING
            },
            "id": STRING,
            "isOnline": BOOLEAN,
            "isUnread": BOOLEAN,
            "lastActive": NUMBER,
            "name": STRING,
            "participantBanned": BOOLEAN,
            "platform": STRING,
            "secondParticipant": {
                "id": STRING,
                "platform": STRING,
                "userId": STRING
            },
            "secondParticipantId": STRING,
            "state": STRING,
            "unreadMessages": NUMBER
        ]}
    }
}
```

As you can see the data object has different structure depending on a message and it can get large (and there's more than 10 of them).
I don't want to parse everything by hand, field-by-field, ideal solution would of course be:

```
struct ChatJsCommand: Codable {
    let action: String
    let data: Any?
}
self.jsonDecoder.decode(ChatJsCommand.self, from: jsonData))
```

Of course because of Any this can't conform to Codable. I can of course extract manually only the action field, create a map of actions (enum) to struct types and then do `JSONDecoder().decode(self.commandMap[ActionKey], data: jsonData)`. This solution would probably also require some casting to proper struct types to use the objects after parsing.
But maybe someone has a better approach? So the class isn't 300 lines? Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, there's like 10 messages only but would love to avoid a blob struct for parsing, nevertheless thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Basically you just use a custom init so that you can decode `action` and use its value to tell you what struct to use to decode `data`. See the linked question and  answers.

Comment: @matt I am not sure it's an exact duplicate. It's not about unknown keys, therefore you don't need customized `CodingKeys` here.

Comment: @Sulthan You can undupe if you like, that's you're prerogative; I won't be offended. But it does seem to me that the question "how do I proceed differently on the second key based on the value of the first key" is completely answered on SO already.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54020428/6630644

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50674899/6630644

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by defining a protocol for data, it can be an empty protocol. That will help us later:

```
protocol MessageData: Decodable {
}
```

Now let's prepare our data objects:

```
struct ErrorData: MessageData {
   let code: String
   let exception: String
   let status: Int
}

struct MessageRequestData: MessageData {
   let recipientUserId: String
   let platform: String
   let content: String
}
```

(use optionals where needed)

Now, we also have to know the data types:

```
enum ActionType: String {
   case ready
   case error
   case messageRequest
}
```

And now the hard part:

```
struct Response: Decodable {
   let action: ActionType
   let data: MessageData?

   private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case action
       case data
   }

   public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      let action = try values.decode(ActionType.self, forKey: .action)

      self.action = action

      switch action {
         case .ready:
             data = nil
         case .messageRequest:
             data = try values.decode(MessageRequestData.self, forKey: .data)
         case .error:
             data = try values.decode(ErrorData.self, forKey: .data)                 
      }
   }
}
```

The only trick is to decode `action` first and then parse depending on the value inside. The only problem is that when using `Response`, you always have to check `action` first and then cast `data` to the type you need.
That could be alleviated by merging `action` and `data` into one enumeration with associated objects, e.g. :

```
enum Action {
   case ready
   case error(ErrorData)
   case messageRequest(MessageRequestData)
   case unknown
}

struct Response: Decodable {           
   let action: Action

   private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case action
      case data
   }

   public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
       let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
       let actionString = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .action)

       switch actionString {
          case "ready":
             action = .ready
          case "messageRequest":
             let data = try values.decode(MessageRequestData.self, forKey: .data)
             action = .messageRequest(data)
          case "error":
             let data = try values.decode(ErrorData.self, forKey: .data)
             action = .error(data)                 
          default: 
             action = .unknown             
       }
   }
}
```