# How to determine and set the type of Object of a parameter from a different parameter in JSON in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, generics

How can I implement a solution where I could set the type of a parameter on the go while parsing a JSON by analyzing the parameter at the same level as the other parameter?

```
let sampleData = Data("""
[
  {
  "type": "one",
  "body": {
    "one": 1
  },
  .
  .
  .
},
  {
  "type": "two",
  "body": {
    "two": 2,
    "twoData": "two"
  },
  .
  .
  .
}
]
""".utf8)

struct MyObject: Codable {
  let type: String
  let body: Body
}

struct Body: Codable {
  let one, two: Int?
  let twoData: String?
}

print(try JSONDecoder().decode([MyObject].self, from: sampleData))
```

Here you can see that the keys in `Body` are all optionals. My solution requires they being parsed into different types according to the value given in the parameter `type`. How can I parse body into the following 2 separate types according to the value I receive in `type`?

```
struct OneBody: Decodable {
  let one: Int
}

struct TwoBody: Decodable {
  let two: Int
  let twoData: String
}
```

Comment: @Sh_Khan The above post was helpful. Can you clarify if there is a way to determine type using a parameter instead of just trying with different objects until it succeeds?

Comment: Similar question (and similar answer) here https://stackoverflow.com/q/54700409/669586

Answer (score 0):

The approach that I finally went with is with a custom `init(from decoder: Decoder)` method where the type is determined first and then using a `switch` statement iterate through each `case` to decode each type and assign it to the body as another `enum`. Here is the code:

```
struct MyObject: Decodable {
  let body: MyBody

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    let type = try container.decode(MyType.self, forKey: .type)
    switch type {
    case .one:
      body = .one(try container.decode(OneBody.self, forKey: .body))
    case .two:
      body = .two(try container.decode(TwoBody.self, forKey: .body))
    }
  }

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case type, body
  }
}

enum MyType: String, Decodable {
  case one, two
}

enum MyBody: Decodable {
  case one(OneBody)
  case two(TwoBody)
}

struct OneBody: Decodable {
  let one: Int
}

struct TwoBody: Decodable {
  let two: Int
  let twoData: String
}

print(try JSONDecoder().decode([MyObject].self, from: sampleData))
```

PS: Please post an answer or a comment if there are any ideas for a better approach.